# Index out of bounds exception trying to create ArrayList with 1-based indices

Tags: java, arraylist

So up until this point I've just used `points.add(new Point(x,y))` to add points to my `ArrayList`. However, I found out that I need the first point to be in index=1 in order to make it possible to multiply the number for each step. So I tried setting the `counter` from `0` to `1`, and as expected I knew I would get a error because of the range, but I've tried changing up the condition within the while-loop, but nothing seems to work.

Here's my code:

```
ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
int counter = 1;
int nPoints = 12;
while (counter <= nPoints) {
    x = (int) (centerX + r * Math.cos(start));
    y = (int) (centerY + r * Math.sin(start));

    points.set(counter, (new Point(x, y)));
    //points.add(new Point(x,y));

    counter++;
}
```

This is the error that I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0   
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)   
    at java.util.ArrayList.set(Unknown Source)
```

I've deleted much of the code that isn't relevant for this problem in order to make it easier to read.

**Edit:**

```
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            a = getWidth() /2;
            b = getHeight() /2;
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);

            //draw cirle
            g2d.drawOval(a-r, b-r, 2*r, 2*r);

            //draw lines
            for (int  i= 1; i < points.size();i ++) {
                g2d.drawLine(points.get(i).x, points.get(i).y, points.get(i+1).x, points.get(i+1).y);

            }

           g2d.dispose();
        }
```

I've created a circle in which I'm trying to draw lines between points along the circumference. Here I want the 1st point to connect to 2, 2 to 4, 3 to 6, 4 to 8 and so on... So the pattern here is is that it is multiplied by 2 for each time. So my initial thought was that I could use the `i` inside the `for`-loop to multiply by 2 each time. But since I have my first point in i=0 inside the ArrayList, I am having trouble.

Comment: If you only need it for multiplying, why not just using `index+1`?

Comment: You cannot set an element beyond the length of the array. You could, put a null in the list, so that the 0'th element is null and the 1 element is where your points start. (not recommended). You could use a Map<Integer, Point> which would behave a bit like you are trying.

Comment: I'm going to use the list later in the code to draw. So if I just start from 1 when I'm drawing, that means I am not including the first point stored in index=0.

Comment: Your comment doesn't make sense. Just use a normal list and don't make the first element 1.

Comment: Java uses 0 based indexes, don't try to make it use 1 based indexes. You have completely fabricated a problem, that should not exist. Once you get a little bit more familiar with java, feel free to use 1-based indixes, there are plenty of hacks you can use.

Comment: This doesn't help me in any way. I am asking for help in order to get around this problem.

Comment: Use for(int i=0; i<points.size()-1; i++){...}

Comment: If you read my edit you'll see that this prevents me from multipying the index.

Comment: First off. Nowhere in your post do you "multiply the index". Here is what has happened, you have encountered a smaller arithmetic challenge. Your solution to this challenge is to use an array with the first element referenced by 1 instead of 0. This is not the only solution to your problem. It is also a bad solution because java uses 0 to reference the first element. Lets go back to your arithmatic problem and solve that. I believe the very first comment correctly addresses your issue, but for the sake of clarity, lets sort through it.

Comment: By the way: for(int index=0; index<points.size(); index++){ int counter = index+1;} voila. use your counter for multiplication.

Comment: That didn't make any sense, whatsoever. Now you're just pointing me back to what was my original problem. What difference does it make that you put int `counter=index+1` inside the loop? I still need to get the point out from `index=1`, which I can't do since the first point is placed in `index=0`. Adding `points.add(null)` didn't work either.

Comment: In your question you never use the index or counter for multiplying. Nobody can help you with this problem, until you figure out what you need and convey it in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Your trying to set an `index` that doesn't exist.

The size of your `ArrayList` is 0 but you are trying to access index `1` which doesn't exist.

You can use `ArrayList.add()` to add another element to your `ArrayList`. If you use `set()` the `index` must actually exist in the `ArrayList`.

Comment: I did because you originally posted it with just the first two sentences, which weren't very helpful. Correct but not helpful.

Comment: @JohnKugelman actually it was helpful it described his problem and why the exception was being thrown.

Comment: @JohnKugelman we will have to agree to disagree. You should be more concerned with helping people and less concerned with downvoting...

Answer (score 0):

To insert an element at index `0` use `points.add(null);` before loop.

So the final code looks like:

```
ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
int counter = 1;
int nPoints = 12;
points.add(null); // <= this line was added
while (counter <= nPoints) {
    x = (int) (centerX + r * Math.cos(start));
    y = (int) (centerY + r * Math.sin(start));

    //points.set(counter, (new Point(x, y))); // <= it's not correct use
    points.add(new Point(x,y));

    counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `add` instead of `set`. You can not set (replace) an item that does not exist. From the docs on [`set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set%28int,%20E%29):

> **Replaces** the element at the specified position in this list with the specified element.

You can use `index + 1` for your calulations, but list indices should start at 0.

Edit:

```
//draw lines
for (int  i= 0; i < points.size() - 1;i ++){
    g2d.drawLine(points.get(i).x,
    points.get(i).y, points.get(i+1).x,
    points.get(i+1).y);
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your comment right, but, you're trying to say that I should just keep it the way I had: `points.add( new Point(x, y));` and `counter` set to 0. But in my `for`-loop inside the `paint`-method, I should use `index+1`?

Comment: Yes. Use an offset of 1 from the index. You didn't  show the calculations but that's what your description indicates.

Comment: Ok, so here's my problem: `for (int  i= 0; i < points.size()-1;i ++) {
    g2d.drawLine(points.get(i).x, points.get(i).y, points.get(i+1).x, points.get(i+1).y); }` So then if I start `int i=1`, then I won't be including the first point since the ArrayList is starting from 0. Am I missing something?

Comment: My ultimate goal is that `i` should be 1 in `for (int i=0...`

Comment: Where do you need `1, 2, 3, ...` instead of `0, 1, 2, ...`? That's where you're going to use `i + 1`. When accessing the ArrayList use `i` as is.

Comment: You should add more details to you're question and present some more of your logic. It's unclear what `i*2` is to acheive here.

Comment: I don't see any changes in your snippet different from mine..?

Comment: @rasperryPi the limit of the for loop is different, since you need to have a "next element" (so only iterate to the one before last element, which is size-1)

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList`s in Java do not extend to the desired length if you try to set a value outside of it's range. You are trying to set item at index 1, when the array has 0 length. Try this:

```
ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
points.add(null);
for (int counter = 0; counter < nPoints; counter++) {
    x = (int) (centerX + r * Math.cos(start));
    y = (int) (centerY + r * Math.sin(start));

    points.add(new Point(x,y));
}
points.set(0, points.get(1));
```

EDIT: you are generating the same `Point` nPoints times. Do something with the angle, for example:

```
x = (int) (centerX + r * Math.cos(start + counter * 0.01));
y = (int) (centerY + r * Math.sin(start + counter * 0.01));
```

EDIT: replacing the 0th element with the 1st

EDIT: now that you provided the paint code, I see that your algorithm does not necessarily use 1-based indices. By the way I highly doubt that you got a null point out of the list. I suspect that even your list is not saved, and got null pointer exception on the list, not on the point. Anyway, try this:

```
ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
for (int counter = 0; counter < nPoints; counter++) {
    x = (int) (centerX + r * Math.cos(start));
    y = (int) (centerY + r * Math.sin(start));

    points.add(new Point(x,y));
}

// ...

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    a = getWidth() /2;
    b = getHeight() /2;
    g2d.setColor(Color.RED);

    //draw cirle
    g2d.drawOval(a-r, b-r, 2*r, 2*r);

    //draw lines
    for (int  i= 1; i < points.size();i ++) {
        g2d.drawLine(points.get(i - 1).x, points.get(i - 1).y, points.get(i).x, points.get(i).y);
    }

    g2d.dispose();
}
```

Comment: @rasperryPi then I'm afraid of you will have to share the code that draws. Anyway, I have found inconsistency in your code, see edit

Comment: Yes. I'm aware of that, I removed all that in order to make it easier to read. I thought I would be confusing having stuff that didn't really matter for my problem.

Comment: @rasperryPi Okay, I didn't know that. Could you please tell us what was the error when running this code?

Comment: Sure! This is the error I'm getting: `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: @raspberryPi Are you sure you are not reading the 0th element of the list? Try duplicating the first point, se acessing the 0th and 1st element will result in the same object, see edit

Comment: I suspect that your list is null. Please double check that you save the generated list to a field, and see my edit

Answer (score 0):

In my case that helped:

```
if (!listName.isEmpty()) {
            return listName.get(0);
        }
```

Hope it works by you ☺️